# How to add an Facebook Like button to the about-secion in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, facebook, ipad, facebook-like

I've finally managed to add an Like button to my website, using the OpenGraph protocol and that FBXML thing, similar to this:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://mywebsiteURL.com" layout="button_count" colorscheme="dark"></fb:like>
```

In my iPhone app there's an UIWebView for my about-section. It would be cool if I could add an Like-Button there too, which points to my app presentation website. Of course I can't expect that the user is online all the time, but probably they're going to tap that button only when they really can (i.e. when online!).

But I guess it's stupid to add this code to my offline-html page shipped with my app, since it refers to a lot of online sources? I also must adopt that strange fb scheme which the browser has to lookup online, right?

What's the best option?